# Deploying List Instance - LookupMulti Type Column in XML

Tags: list, lookup-column, xml

So I have been able to populate rows with `Lookup` type fields as such:

```
<ListInstance ... >
  <Data>
    <Rows>
      <Row>
        <Field Name="LookupColumn">2;#LookupValue</Field>
      </Row>
    </Rows>
  </Data>
</ListInstance>
```

But how do I populate multiple values in the same manner for a `LookupMulti` typed field?

I can get one value, but have been unable to figure out how to populate more.

## Relevant XML

Schema.xml

```
  <Field ID="{69FCEC38-3F15-48DB-891E-D76EF66A02A4}"
         Name="MultiLookupColumn"
         Type="LookupMulti"
         List="Lists/Target"
         ShowField="Title"
         Mult="true"
         DisplayName="MultiLookupColumn"
         Required="false"/>
```

Elements.xml

```
<ListInstance ... >
  <Data>
    <Rows>
      <Row>
        <Field Name="MultiLookupColumn">1;#Value1;#2;#Value2</Field>
      </Row>
    </Rows>
  </Data>
</ListInstance>
```

<strike>I know the schema is right because I can add multiple items via the AddItem.aspx form.</strike>

## Edit

The schema may be wrong. The form allows me to add multiple but when I do still only the first value displays.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.tostring.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try 1;#LV1;#2;#LV2;#3;#LV3. Each item seperated by ;#

Comment: useful answer! note: no need to specify title, just ID means and it gets correct titles!

Answer (score 5):

My problem was resolved by changing `Mult="true"` to `Mult="TRUE"` but this was not what I asked.

Comment: Thank's a lot. But is really weird. What's the difference?

Comment: I still have no idea why, but I'm assuming it just doesn't parse the lowercase "true" correctly... for whatever reason... since this incident I've always used all uppercase "TRUE"s everywhere and haven't had any problems like this again. Truly weird.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only using id's, it worked for me only with:

> 1;#;#2;#;#3